# Is it true that if $X$ follows central chi-square distribution then $X+a$ follows non-central chi-square distribution where $a$ is positive constant?

Tags: probability, distributions, chi-squared-distribution

Is it true that if $X$ follows a central chi-square distribution, then $X+a$ follows a non-central chi-square distribution where $a$ is a positive constant?

Comment: Cannot be true, since a non-central chi-square also has range $(0, \infty)$

Comment: Where did you read that $X+a$ follows a non-central chi-square distribution? Giving a full quotation of the statement(s) that made you believe that might help clarifying the things you did not understand. (As Kjetil points out, it cannot be true that $X+a$ follows a non-central chi-square distribution).

Comment: Airing what @J-J-J said, validating an assertion without proper citation defeats the purpose and leads to no significant progress in either of the parties involved in the discussion.

Comment: Could just be a conjecture that the OP came up with?

Comment: @ChristophHanck My suspicion is that OP simply misinterpreted something they read (which happens all the time with people learning statistics, including myself). It would be interesting to know the thought process (and possibly related quotations) that lead them to this conclusion, so we can clarify things for them and for other people who might reach the same erroneous conclusion.

Comment: @ChristophHanck, sure. My problem is this conjecture (again as stated by J-J-J) might have stemmed from another bigger problem which OP wanted to solve but for some reason thought that conjecture would have solved the problem in hand. A context of the original problem would on turn help OP in a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the constants already "enter" at the stage of considering non-zero mean normal random variables that are *then* squared and added up to form a non central $\chi^2$.

More specifically, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution, let $(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots, X_{k})$ be $k$ independent, normally distributed random variables with means $\mu _{i}$ and unit variances. Then,
$$\sum _{i=1}^{k}X_{i}^{2}$$
is distributed as noncentral chi-squared with parameters $k$ (the number of degrees of freedom) and non-centrality parameter
$$\lambda:=\sum _{i=1}^{k}\mu _{i}^{2}$$

So to give a simple special case, consider $k=1$ and $X:=Y+\mu$ where $Y\sim N(0,1)$. Then, $X^2\sim\chi^2(1,\mu^2)$. But, clearly,
$$
X^2=Y^2+2Y\mu+\mu^2,
$$
such that what is added to the central $\chi^2$ r.v. $Y^2$ is not some constant $a$, but the r.v. $2Y\mu+\mu^2$. Since $Y$ can take negative values, we retain the support on $(0,\infty)$, as pointed out by Kjetil. In particular, when $Y=-\mu$, $X=0$.